# print one line before match in sed between patterns

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following code in a text file:

```
def test_one():
'''
Test case steps:
step1: STEP1
step2: STEP2
'''
x = "this"
assert 'h' in x

def test_two():
    '''
    Test case steps:
    step3: STEP3
    step4: STEP4
    '''
    x = "this"
    assert 'h' in x
```

I need to get the steps with the test case name, used sed to get the pattern

```
sed -n -e "/'''/,/'''/p" test_create_doc.py
```

After using sed:

```
'''
Test case steps:
step1: STEP1
step2: STEP2
'''
'''
Test case steps:
step3: STEP3
step4: STEP4
'''
```

Need one line before the match ,Expected output is as below:
I need get one line before the match pattern.

```
test_one
'''
Test case steps:
step1: STEP1
step2: STEP2
'''
test_two
'''
Test case steps:
step3: STEP3
step4: STEP4
'''
```

Please let me know how to take the one line before the pattern match.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick fix where you can match multiple patterns in sed

```
sed -n -e "/def/,//p" -e "/'''/,/'''/p" test_create_doc.py
```

**sample output**

```
def test_one():
    '''
    '''
    Test case steps:
    step1: STEP1
    step2: STEP2
    '''
def test_two():
    '''
    '''
    Test case steps:
    step3: STEP3
    step4: STEP4
    '''
```

PS: There may be better ways of achieving what you are trying here. 
Maybe have a look at pydocs and how to generate them

Answer (score 0):

This is easy and readable in Awk.

```
awk "/'''/,/'''/ { if(p) { print p; p='' } print }
    { p = $2; sub(/\\(.*/, '', p) }" file
```

Awk scripts would usually be inside single quotes, but in this case, double quotes are convenient, and there is only one backslash which needs to be doubled (inside double quotes, the shell will mess with dollar signs, backticks, and backslashes. If you ever need to put a single quote in an Awk string inside single quotes, use the octal escape `\047`).

I'm sure this is possible in `sed` to; but I would not want to document and maintain that script.